# Passing Selenium opened URL to Scrapy and scraping the data

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

I've been trying to scrape Bioshock games from the steam store and save their name, price and link in a CSV file. I know how to do it just by using Scrapy, but I really want to know if there's a way to do it combining both Scrapy and Selenium. I want to use Selenium just to get rid of the age check gate that pops up on certain game store sites.

[Example of an age gate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keH0A.png)

[Example of another age gate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0fuM.png)

So I've managed to scrape games that don't have the age gate by using Scrapy and I've managed to bypass the age gates using Selenium.

The problem I'm having is passing the game store site that Selenium opened by bypassing the age gate to Scrapy so it can crawl it. Since everything works fine on its own I came to the conclusion that the problem is that I don't know how to connect them.

```
def parse_product(self, response):
    product = ScrapesteamItem()
    sel = self.driver
    #Passing first age gate
    if '/agecheck/app/' in response.url:
        sel.get(response.url)
        select = Select(sel.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="ageYear"]"""))
        select.select_by_visible_text("1900")
        sel.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="agecheck_form"]/a""").click()
        #Pass Selenium newly opened site to Scrapy
    #Passing second age gate
    elif '/agecheck' in response.url:
        sel.get(response.url)
        sel.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="app_agegate"]/div[3]/a[1]""").click()
        #Pass Selenium newly opened site to Scrapy
    #Scraping the data with scrapy
    else:
        name = response.css('.apphub_AppName ::text').extract()
        price = response.css('div.game_purchase_price ::text, div.discount_final_price ::text').extract()
        link = response.css('head > link:nth-child(40) ::attr(href)').extract()

        for product in zip(name, price, link):
            scrapedInfo = {
                'NAME' : product[0],
                'PRICE' : product[1].rstrip().lstrip(),
                'LINK' : product[2]
            }

            yield scrapedInfo
```

I hope someone will know how to do it (if it's even possible).

P.S. I know there are much better ways to scrape Steam store, I know there's an API probably but before I go and learn that I would like to know if there's a way to do it like this even if it's sub-optimal.

Comment: I would strongly suggest using a combination of `BeautifulSoup` and `selenium`. Use `selenium` to interact with the webpage via an automated browser and pass the page source HTML to `BeautifulSoup` to parse and extract what you want.

Comment: Sure, I'll try it out. Can you tell me how do I pass the page source HTML in Selenium and why do you favour BeautifulSoup compared to Scrapy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The straight away answer will be: apply same scraping code that you did use for Scraping the data with scrapy, i.e. something like this:

```
from scrapy.spiders import xxxxxxxSpider

class MySpider(SitemapSpider):
    sitemap_urls = ['http://www.xxxxxxxSpider.com']
    sitemap_rules = [
        ('/product/', 'parse_product'),        
    ]

    def my_custom_parse_product(self, response):
        name = response.css('.apphub_AppName ::text').extract()
            price = response.css('div.game_purchase_price ::text, div.discount_final_price ::text').extract()
            link = response.css('head > link:nth-child(40) ::attr(href)').extract()

            for product in zip(name, price, link):
                scrapedInfo = {
                    'NAME' : product[0],
                    'PRICE' : product[1].rstrip().lstrip(),
                    'LINK' : product[2]
                }

                yield scrapedInfo

    def parse_product(self, response):
        product = ScrapesteamItem()
        sel = self.driver
        #Passing first age gate
        if '/agecheck/app/' in response.url:
            sel.get(response.url)
            select = Select(sel.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="ageYear"]"""))
            select.select_by_visible_text("1900")
            sel.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="agecheck_form"]/a""").click()
            #Pass Selenium newly opened site to Scrapy
            response = HtmlResponse(url=response.url, body=driver.page_source) 
            #scrapy.http.Response(url=response.url, body=driver.page_source) 
            self.parse(response);               
        #Passing second age gate
        elif '/agecheck' in response.url:
            sel.get(response.url)
            sel.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="app_agegate"]/div[3]/a[1]""").click()
            #Pass Selenium newly opened site to Scrapy
            response = HtmlResponse(url=response.url, body=driver.page_source) 
            #scrapy.http.Response(url=response.url, body=driver.page_source) 
            self.parse(response); 
        #Scraping the data with scrapy
        else:
            my_custom_parse_product(response) #will actually scrap data
```

But it may appear that age protected pages will contain same data, but in different elements (not in *response.css('.apphub_AppName ::text')* for instance) in this case you will need to implement own scrape code for each page type

Comment: Sadly for some reason it doesn't work. It just won't write to a CSV file. By doing it that way only the games that do not have the age gate get written to the CSV file. I think it has to do with the argument you're trying to pass to my_custom_parse_product function. You are passing the response object that Scrapy provided and not the one opened by selenium. The response argument you're passing there has nothing to do with the website opened by Selenium once it passes the age gate. The page gets opened but it does not get scraped. No errors are shown, webdriver opens it and Scrapy does nothing.